# How to move a plane - solidworks

Tags: plane, solidworks

I am going to mirror some features, and thus I am trying to create plane in the middle of the design. When I go Features>Reference Geometry>Plane , it asks for 3 points to select in order to construct the plane. However under First Reference tab, there is no option for Offset distance. According to 2011 Solidworks Help, that option should be available. If it was available, I was going to use offset to put the plane in the middle of the design.

Do you know what the problem can be? Or how can I give an offset to the plane after creating it? I do not want to move it by hand. It is not accurate.

Here is the solidworks 2011 screenshot:

[image: Solidworks Image Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can select a surface to create a plane rather than selecting dots. My problem was due to selection filters, I could not select a surface.

Answer (score 0):

Click on surface that defines your plane.
Create Geometry.
Choose your distance offset.

In your image you are defining what appears to be a flat surface with your part.  Also, if you move that surface, it will cascade an error onto everything that will later be defined by the plane you make.

My experience with doing these type of part say design your part about a central plane instead of creating it outward from the origin.  SolidWorks can be very picky as to how you plan the part.